# How do I click an element using selenium and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I click an element using selenium and beautifulsoup in python? I got these lines of code and I find it difficult to achieve. I want to click every element in every iteration. There are no pagination or next page. There are only like about 10 elements and after clicking the last element, it should stop. Does anyone know what should I do. Here are my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
url = 'https://www.99.co/singapore/condos-apartments/a-treasure-trove'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

details = soup.select('.FloorPlans__container__rwH_w') //Whole container of the result


for d in details:
    picture = d.find('span',{'class':'Tappable-inactive'}).click() //the single element.
    print(d)


driver.close()
```

Here is the site https://www.99.co/singapore/condos-apartments/a-treasure-trove . I want to scrape the details and the image in every floor plans section but it is difficult because the image only appears after you click the specific element. I can only get the details except for the image itself. Try it yourself so that you know what I mean.

EDIT: 
I tried this method

```
for d in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="floorPlans"]/div/div/div/div/span'):

    d.click()
```

The problem is it clicks too fast that the image couldn't load. And also im using selenium here. Is there any method like selecting a beautifulsoup like this format `picture = d.find('span',{'class':'Tappable-inactive'}).click()` ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot interact with website widgets by using beautifulSoup you need to work with **selenium.** There are 2 ways to handle this problem.

- First is to get the main wrapper (class) of the 10 elements and then iterate to each child element of the main class.
- You can get the element by xpath and increment the last number in xpath by one in each iteration to move to the next element.

Comment: I did use selenium sir

Comment: I just dont know how to mix them

Comment: You donot need to mix them. We use selenium when we need to interact with web page with the help of code that including clicking , scrolling and much more. Beautiful soup doesn't support such events like clicking ..

Answer (score 0):

I print some result to check your code.

"details" only has one item.
And "picture" is not element. (So it's not clickable.)

```
details = soup.select('.FloorPlans__container__rwH_w')
print(details)
print(len(details))


for d in details:
    print(d)
    picture = d.find('span',{'class':'Tappable-inactive'})
    print(picture)
```

Output:
[image]

For your edited version, you can check images have been visible before you do click().

Use visibility_of_element_located to do.

Reference: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: there is an image attribute in the div sir. Kindly visit the site i provided